# How to export graphics from GraphPad Prism 6 to LaTeX?

Tags: graphics, import

I use GraphPad Prism 6 to make some scientific graphics. Always I import them to LaTex like an image with `includegraphics`, but unfortunately those images lose quality and the font is not the same in axis or other graphic items.

Someone knows if there is a way to import graphics from GraphPad?

I'd like to have the graphpad graphics like pgfplots graphics

Comment: Well, depending on how complex the graphs are and how much time you want to spend on them, you *could* make them directly in pgf plot. And you could always ask questions here if you have questions along the way.

Comment: @heather really the graphics that I do in GraphPad, generally are columns and bars with standard deviation lines, etc. I don't work really good with that graphics in pgfplots, and the GraphPad columns and bars grahics are more beautiful

Comment: My apologies; just a suggestion (though your reasoning makes sense). I don't suppose you'd be okay with anything other than GraphPad?

Comment: If GraphPad can export to pdf, the pdf should have lossless quality. The only difference then would be that the text in the pdf would be typeset på GraphPad and the document through LaTeX, which gives a different look. Do you have an example of how this graph should look like?

Comment: You could also export it as pdf and import it to InkSpace, where you can export the pdf with LaTeX-support, so that you can is it within your document, with LaTeX typesetting the text.

Comment: https://www.graphpad.com/scientific-software/prism/  says it will export to EPS if when it does so text is text (rather than the whole image being a bitmap wrapped as eps) then you could use psfrag to overlay latex typeset text over the image